# Auto Refreshing selectbox after submitting form and updating database

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu, refresh

I have a form where the user can update some content. One of the fields to be updated is a selectbox that is pre-populated with data from a database. However, if the user wants to add a new option to that selectbox, I would like them to be able to click an "Add New Item" button below the selectbox, have that link launch a modal with a form in it, and fill out the textbox in the modal form. When they hit the submit button in the modal form, I would like the modal to close and the original selectbox to show the new record that was added to the database without refreshing the entire page.

I hope this makes sense.

Here is the selectbox in the main form:

```
<select name="brand" style="width: 100%;">
  <option value="select">Brand Name...</option>
  <?php
  include 'ahdb.php';
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM Brand_Name WHERE active='1'";
  $sql_result = mysqli_query($sql, $connection) or die ('Could not select the Brand Name Categories');
  while ($brand = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
    echo "<option value='" .$brand['brand_name_id']. "'>" .$brand['brand_name']. "</option>";
  }
  ?>
</select>
<a href="#brandForm">Add New Brand Item</a>
```

I already have the modal pop-up working fine on the page, but here is the code for the form inside of the modal:

```
<form name="brandForm" method="post" action="processForm.php">
<input type="text" name="new-item">
<input type="submit" name="new-item-submit" value="Add New Item">
</form>
```

Here is the little bit of jQuery and Ajax that I am using for the modal and the modal form. What am I missing to get the original selectbox to auto-refresh without refreshing the entire page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var messageDelay = 2000;  // How long to display status messages (in milliseconds)

// Init the form once the document is ready
$( init );

// Initialize the form

function init() {

// Hide the form initially.
// Make submitForm() the form's submit handler.
// Position the form so it sits in the centre of the browser window.
$('#brandForm').submit( submitForm ).addClass( 'positioned' );

$('a[href="#brandForm"]').click( function() {
$('#overlay').fadeIn( 'slow' );
$('#brandForm').fadeIn( 'slow', function() {
  $('#brandName').focus();
} )

return false;
} );


// When the OVERLAY DIV is clicked, close the form
$('#overlay').click( function() {
$('#brandForm').fadeOut();
$('#overlay').fadeOut( 'slow' );
} );

// Submit the form via Ajax

function submitForm() {

var brandForm = $(this);

$.ajax( {
  url: brandForm.attr( 'action' ) + "?ajax=true",
  type: brandForm.attr( 'method' ),
  data: brandForm.serialize(),
  success: submitFinished
} );
}

// Prevent the default form submission occurring
return false;
}

// Handle the Ajax response

function submitFinished( response ) {
response = $.trim( response );

if ( response == "success" ) {

// Form submitted successfully:
// 1. Display the success message
// 2. Clear the form fields
// 3. Fade the content back in

$('#brandName').val( "" );

$('#overlay').delay(messageDelay+500).fadeOut( 'slow' );

}  }
}

</script>
```

Here is the processForm.php script that the modal form submits to:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'ahdb.php'; //connect to database

// Read the form values
$success = false;
$brandName = isset( $_POST['brandName'] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^\.\-\' a-zA-Z0-9]/", "", $_POST['brandName'] ) : "";

// Return an appropriate response to the browser
if ( isset($_GET["ajax"]) ) {
echo $success ? "success" : "error";

//insert into database before sending response to the browser
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `Brand_Name` (brand_name) VALUES ('$brandName')");

}
?>
```

I am able to get the modal form to add the value to the database, but when the modal closes, I cannot get the original selectbox to show the new item added without refreshing the entire page, which I do not want.

Please help.

Thanks so much.

Comment: You should use ajax ;)

Comment: I figured that ajax would be the solution, but I really don't know anything about ajax. Do you have any ajax solutions you could offer me? That would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with JQuery?

Comment: I have used a little bit of jQuery, but I am in no way proficient with it. I actually use a bit of jquery for the modal pop-up, but that's about it.

Comment: I have even used a bit of ajax in the past, but I wouldn't know how to use what I have in the past to fit what I am needing to do. That is how limited my knowledge is of both ajax and jquery.

Comment: You should try this tuto: http://ec2-54-227-92-167.compute-1.amazonaws.com/en/courses/javascript-beginner-en-g7vdk/0/1

Comment: I went ahead and added a bit of the jQuery, PhP and Ajax code that I used for my modal pop-up and for inserting the information into the database. I just cant seem to get the original selectbox to auto-refresh without refreshing the whole page. What do I need to do differently?